# Cross-browser CSS for left align and right align on the same line

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser, text-alignment

Cross-browser CSS that works to allow both left and right align of text on the same line?

Example (where each text quote should be aligned as far left or right as possible, respectively):

```
stuff on the right                                              stuff on the left
```

- No float's answer's please.. unless there is a way to make the text *not* break out of the parent div/container in a multicolumn css page...

Comment: basically looking for `<div align="right">` and `<div align="left">` - except in the case where the newline isn't automatically enforced with each div.

Comment: It isn't enforced. It is because a div is displayed as a block that occupies the whole width of the container. You can do display:inline and it will not occupy the entire width of the container.

Comment: The 2 answers so far don't actually break layouts as a rule:  http://jsfiddle.net/UNSYQ/.  There must be something else going on with your code that causes the suggestions not to work.  One thing to try is setting a width on the floated containers as floats that exceed their available width will drop down, breaking the layout.

Comment: yes, tried for generic @ http://jsfiddle.net/4X4Na/ ... added a `&nbsp;` to existing code, works ... hum, can i award two right answers? :D

Comment: and... center? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324757/cross-browser-css-for-left-align-right-align-and-center-align-on-the-same-line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With container tags:

```
<div>
  <p style="float: left">stuff on the left</p>
  <p style="float: right">Tstuff on the right </p>
</div>
```

With inline tags:

```
<div>
  <span style="float: left">stuff on the left</span>
  <span style="float: right">Tstuff on the right</span>
</div>
```

Comment: @ina: I dont understand. The two bits of text will have to be in separate 'containers' if you want to apply different styling/layout to them

Comment: @barrylloyd - Just added an additional example. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ina - You can style the text from the DIV in either example.

Comment: @ina: I'm not sure what you mean, but you could try adding `<hr style="display:none; clear: both" />` to the end of the container div.

Comment: Had thought span's only did local formatting - btw are span's safer than div's in this case - before I put the `&nbsp;` into my layout, the entire thing went astray (totally went out of containers)...

Answer (score 2):

float:left for the one on the left, and float:right for the one on the right. Or absolute/relative positioning. Pretty sure both work across the main browers.

Comment: no it doesn't. If puts the text to the far left or far right of the container.

Comment: nope, it forces the text out if you are using a multicolumn css layout.. which is most pages nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume this is the HTML code:

```
<div>
  <div id="left" style="float: left">stuff on the left</div>
  <div id="right" style="float: right">Tstuff on the right </div>
</div>
```

What you can do is use JQuery to find the highest div, then set the #left, #right divs with the highest div.
Here's a sample code:

```
if ($('#left').height()<$('#right').height()) {
  $('#left').height($('#right').height());
} else {
  $('#right').height($('#left').height());
}
```

Or you can Google with "equal heights jquery" for other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Without floats:

```
<div class=container style='width: 100%;'>
  <div class=left-side style='display: inline-block; width: 50%'>
    Stuff on the left
  </div>
  <div class=right-side style='display: inline-block; width: 50%; text-align: right'>
    Stuff on the right
  </div>
</div>
```