# Cross-browser CSS for left align, right align AND center align on the same line

Tags: css, layout, cross-browser, text-alignment

Similar to [this easy one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3324694/cross-browser-css-for-left-align-and-right-align-on-the-same-line), except how do you get a third text group to show up dead center, along with one "dead left", and one "dead right"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
<p style="float: left; width: 33%;">stuff on the left</p>
<p style="float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center">center</p>
<p style="float: right; width: 33%; text-align: right">stuff on the right </p>
</div>
```